# rails console, rbenv and rbenv-vars issues in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rbenv, rbenv-vars

Im experiencing a bizzare issue in ubuntu 20.04.
I've installed ruby 3.1.2, rails 6.1.5, rbenv and rbenv-vars.
Set up inside the app directory the .rbenv-vars with

```
RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=123456
```

Whenever i try rails console i get a bunch of lines starting with:

> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:27:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/pop (LoadError)
>
> from ... lots of froms ...

I have tested that the ENV's are loading but i have no access to rails console.

When i remove the .rbenv-vars completely, i can run rails console but without enviroment variables, railsloads in developer and not production mode.

Although inside the server block i have `passport_app_env production;`

I haven't found a solution yet... any hints?

---- Quick Update ----

Since it is my first attempt to develop & deploy a Rails app, i think i've started the project in a 'wrong' way.
Many months ago started the project locally and not until recently decided to combine local (development) & remote (production) since the project progressed to an ok level.
My realization now is that I should have started local & remote from the beginning.
I've stumbled into many bizzare issues in production mode which didn't make sense and lost plenty of time searching and researching.

To make things pragmatic i decided to port my app to Rails 7 (from Rails 6) and combine local (dev) & remote (capistrano/production) along the way.

My current status: So far so good. App is progressing in Rails 7 solving issues in Rails 7 where worked on Rails 6 (atm: devise) and it's live on digitalocean.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` has the right (original) value. If it's wrong, you'll not get this working.

Or you can create new master.key with `EDITOR="nano" rails credentials:edit` and then save the master.key's value in `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`

Comment: i have copy/pasted the value of master.key (from local project) to apps folder / .rbenv-vars as RAILS_MASTER_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxx . With ruby -e 'p ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]' i get the value. I don't think the issue is there.

Comment: are you able to edit credentials?

Comment: yes, i cant edit credentials

Comment: I'm sorry, you wrote `yes i cant`, I don't understand if yes or not  I mean while using rbenv-vars? Anyway try to edit `config/puma.rb` and set `environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "production" }`
 as default environment to see if you can use console

Comment: ahh sorry, yes i can edit the credentials.
The credentials are the same with my local repository.
I've just copied the master key as env variable.